# Checkpointing records with Amazon KCL throws ProvisionedThroughputExceededException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, checkpoint

We are experiencing a `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException` upon checkpointing many events together.

The exception stacktrace is the following:

```
    com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: Rate exceeded for shard shardId-000000000000 in stream mystream under account accountid. (Service: AmazonKinesis; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ProvisionedThroughputExceededException; Request ID: ea36760b-9db3-0acc-bbe9-87939e3270aa)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1529)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1167)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:948)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:635)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:618)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$300(AmazonHttpClient.java:586)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:573)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:445)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.doInvoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1645)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1621)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.getShardIterator(AmazonKinesisClient.java:909)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.proxies.KinesisProxy.getIterator(KinesisProxy.java:291)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.SequenceNumberValidator.validateSequenceNumber(SequenceNumberValidator.java:79)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.RecordProcessorCheckpointer.checkpoint(RecordProcessorCheckpointer.java:120)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.RecordProcessorCheckpointer.checkpoint(RecordProcessorCheckpointer.java:90)
```

As you can see here, the exception is raised at

```
RecordProcessorCheckpointer.java:90
```

inside the KCL library. What does checkpointing has to do with exceeding the throughput?

Answer (score 2):

Kinesis is rate-limited,

PutRecord requests can only process up to the limit of the provisioned throughput on the involved shard. exceeding this will throw `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException`

Obvious solution would be splitting stream's shard into two and divide the hash key space evenly. It might look unnecessary if your metrics are within the limits of a single shard but lets say if you use your limit of `1000 transactions/sec` write capacity in first `500ms` your activity for that shard will be throttled for the remaining half so there is no way you can avoid throttling with a single shard.

You can configure automatic retries after short delays for your throttled requests. check your SDK's documentation if there is any examples of this.

Comment: Checkpointing does not throw this exception, you are only filling an extra column for each row with the associated sequence number by checkpointing...  `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException` is only related to exceeding throughput limits.

Comment: an extra row where ? are we actually adding s new record to kinesis when checkpointing?

Comment: Its hard to help without seeing your code, here is a sample record processor code written in python it might be some help to you. [kclpy](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-python/blob/master/samples/sample_kclpy_app.py)

Comment: The exception is raised on IRecordProcessorCheckpointer.checkpoint invocation

Comment: Sorry man this turned into a guessing game, if you don't provide your code or error logs its not gonna be possible for me to help you.

Comment: It seems I have the same issue. When it hits ProvisionThroughputExceededException, the KCL recordProcessor will stop processing until the next restart.  The checkpoint is call validate as the stacktrace below:

`com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.exceptions.ThrottlingException: Exceeded throughput while getting an iterator for shard shardId-000000000005
 at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.SequenceNumberValidator.validateSequenceNumber(SequenceNumberValidator.java:89) ~[amazon-kinesis-client-1.9.0.jar:na]`